# Enabling AdMob Mediation Without Added Library

Tags: admob, mobile-ad-mediation

What happens when mediation for a network is enabled however a user has an older version of the app without the library for mediated network?

Will this result in an error for the user? Or will mediated request be ignored in that case and only AdMob's ads displayed?

This is on Android (not sure if behavior is different for iOS).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your surmise is correct. On versions of your app that do not contain the network library, that network will be skipped and the next down the chain will be called instead.